# Is this a valid way to approach permutation problems (assigning numbers to them)

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a question like:
There are 4 sets of brothers. So we have $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,C_1,C_2,D_1,D_2$, how many ways can we have it so that each person is not grouped with their brother (in a line)?
I was wondering if we can do some sort of tricky way by "assigning" each person with the same letter a number. e.g. let $A_k = 1$, $B_k = 2$, $C_k = 3$, $D_k = 4$, and then form an integer with this and maybe assess its divisibility by $11$ or something. e.g. When they are lined up with the original line I gave at the top, the integer formed is $11223344$ which is divisible by 11. No idea if this would work, but was wondering if this could ever give rise to a way to approach this question

Comment: how do you want to group them all together?

Comment: In pairs, so that each person is not paired with their brother.

Comment: e.g. $13 14 24 23$ is one way (using my numbering system)

Comment: but this is not a pair. apair consist of only 2.

Comment: I mean they are paired up (more obvious if you add brackets)  
(13)(14)(24)(23)

Comment: a pair is only of two things . for above if you want to find the pairs will be 13   ,24  , 21  ,  43  .all these are different pairs. 13142423 is a group of all those in which brothers are not adjascent to each other

Comment: From your set-up, do you allow the second and third in line to be brothers?  In your groupings, it looks like $13314242$ would be ok because none in each pair $(13)(31)(42)(42)$ are brothers.  This, however, does not seem to be the intent of the problem...

Comment: Ah right. Yes, excluding that case you presented, so $(13)(31)(42)(42)$ is not valid. I made up the problem recently, just to see if it was possible to approach it using that numbering method I outlined (and properties of integers). So apologies for ambiguous question

Comment: "not grouped/paired" should probably be "not adjacent to" a brother.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no convenient number-theoretic way to detect the pair of identical adjacent digits in (for example) $23114234$.

This sort of problem can be approached using exponential generating functions. Each pair of digits is represented as $\tfrac1{2!}x^2-x$. The first term corresponds to $[X][X]$ and the second term to $[XX]$ treated as a single letter (which is subtracted according to the principle of inclusion-exclusion). Then the eight-digit structure is represented as $(\tfrac1{2!}x^2-x)^4$.

When that is expanded, the $x^8$ is replaced with $8!$, the $x^7$ with $7!$, etc. The neatest way to represent that process is with the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(\tfrac1{2!}x^2-x)^4\ {\rm d}x\quad =\quad 864$$

See OEIS [A114938](https://oeis.org/A114938) for more formulas, including the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n+k)!}{2^k}$$